# Problem with update pear

Tags: php, upgrade, pear

I am trying update Pear and I type in console:

```
pear upgrade pear
```

then I got error:

```
Error getting channel info from pear.php.net: Channel pear.php.net does not support xml-rpc method package.listLatestReleases
```

What should I do to upgrade PEAR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a very very very old PEAR version that still uses the XML-RPC protocol. This is not supported anymore since a very long time.

Re-installing PEAR is the only option here.