# PEAR and PHP -- "Error getting channel info" on OS X when upgrade/do anything

Tags: pear, php

I saw this question: [Problem with update pear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828190/problem-with-update-pear) that said the issue is using an outdated version of PEAR, well, I'm using 1.9.4(the latest).

```
dinosaurhunter:~ root# pear -V
PEAR Version: 1.9.4
PHP Version: 5.3.21
Zend Engine Version: 2.3.0
Running on: Darwin dinosaurhunter.network.local 12.2.1 Darwin Kernel Version 12.2.1: Thu Oct 18 16:32:48 PDT 2012; root:xnu-2050.20.9~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

I am using PHP from homebrew.

So weird:

```
dinosaurhunter:~ root# pear upgrade
Error getting channel info from pear.php.net: Connection to `pear.php.net:80' failed: Operation timed out
Error getting channel info from pear.php.net: Connection to `pear.php.net:80' failed: Operation timed out
Error getting channel info from pear.php.net: Connection to `pear.php.net:80' failed: Operation timed out
Error getting channel info from pear.php.net: Connection to `pear.php.net:80' failed: Operation timed out
Error getting channel info from pear.php.net: Connection to `pear.php.net:80' failed: Operation timed out
Nothing to upgrade

dinosaurhunter:~ root# curl pear.php.net:80 | head -n5
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 14420    0 14420    0     0  41953      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 66759
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head >
<link rel="alternate" href="http://blog.pear.php.net/feed/" type="application/rss+xml" title="PEAR News" /> <title>PEAR - PHP Extension and Application Repository</title>
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/gifs/favicon.ico" />
```

I saw some people saying it's a proxy thing -- I don't use a proxy either.

```
dinosaurhunter:~ root# pear config-show | grep -i proxy
HTTP Proxy Server Address      http_proxy       <not set>
```

I'm really lost because the URLs they say are timing out work just fine, I'm not using a proxy, PEAR is up to date -- what else could it be?

**EDIT** did more debugging...

This code works:

```
<?php


error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

ini_set ('allow_url_fopen', 1);

$url = 'http://www.google.com';

// Create a stream
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'timeout'=>60,
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

var_dump($file);
```

However, this doesn't work:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

ini_set ('allow_url_fopen', 1);

$file = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/');
var_dump($file);
```

It fails with:

> Warning: `file_get_contents(http://www.google.com/)`: failed to open stream: Operation timed out

Answer (score 1):

The underlying issue wound up being the `default_socket_timeout` configuration.

It was set like:

```
; Default timeout for socket based streams (seconds)
; http://php.net/default-socket-timeout
default_socket_timeout = unlimited
```

I changed it to

```
; Default timeout for socket based streams (seconds)
; http://php.net/default-socket-timeout
default_socket_timeout = 120
```

and it works.

It looks like `file_get_contents` might not respect a [`default_socket_timeout`](http://php.net/default_socket_timeout) value of "unlimited". Blargh!

Comment: Nice find. Looks like this has been incorrectly configured on your PHP pacakge, it's documented as an integer, not as a string. I would double check with the PHP package and report this issue back to the maintainer.

Answer (score 0):

Run wireshark and check what pear actually does network-wise. You can also run `pear -vvvvvv` to get debug output - that might give you a hint about the problem source.

Comment: Only new output with pear -vvvvvv: `Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to pear.php.net:80 (Operation timed out) in PEAR/REST.php on line 419`

Comment: I have a capture from Wireshark but I'm not sure what I'm looking for... here is an example output from one of the TCP streams: http://i.imgur.com/VpUparA.png

Comment: Your connection gets `RES`et for some unknown reason. I can't help you further, sorry. Strange that curl works.